# Custom Action exe with evaluated privilege for Installsheild Limited edition

Tags: installshield

I am using the Limited edition and in my installer I have a custom action where I open a cmd.exe and passing a batch file for executing.

The cmd is executing but its not in the elevated permission. I need to execute this in elevated permission since my batch file has operations which needs admin privilege.

I tried many options and the screen shots attached describes what I have done.

Let me know if this is possible with Limited Edition. I am installing in windows 10 machine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the whole "Elevetad privilege" thing changed a lot during the lasts years.

if I were you, I'd put the schema to version 500 (the last one)

you'll might wan't to double check that your batch file is correctly found, as properties in system context can be unavailable. (use /k so the cmd prompt will not close and you'll be able to see the result of your batch file.)

also if the UAC is disabled on the client machine the user won't have the right to elevate your installer so setting the `Require Administrative privilege` won't change anything.

in order to be sure, you'll might wan't to use a install condition validating the `Privileged` property.